# why does c++ generate a constructor in the following case?

Tags: c++, testing, move-semantics

I have a class A

```
struct A{
    A(){}

    A(int x): d(x) {}

    A(const A& a): d(a.d) {
        std::cout << "copy construction" << std::endl;
    }

    A(A&& a): d(a.d){
        std::cout << "move construction" << std::endl;
    }

    A& operator=(const A& a){
        std::cout << "copy assignment" << std::endl;
        d = a.d;
        return *this;
    }

    A& operator=(A&& a){
        std::cout << "move assignment" << std::endl;
        d = a.d;
        return *this;
    }

    int d;
};
```

and a function func

```
A func(){
    return A(3);
}
```

if I do this

```
A x;
x = func();
```

the output is "move assignment" as expected
but if I construct A like this

```
A x = func();
```

then nothing is printed as if c++ generates its own move constructor and refuses to use the defined one.

I'm using visual studio 14

I'd really like to understand this.

Thank you for explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor call is elided.

- With gcc, you can disable it with `-fno-elide-constructors`.
- msvc doesn't have equivalent option.

Comment: Elided as in merged? Or omitted altogether as part of compiler optimization?

Comment: hm ok I didn't know this behavior

Comment: @HappyCoder Omitted. Merged makes no sense in this context.

Comment: Yeah @Barry. Realized that later.